# Address of bound member function

Tags: c++, function

I have a the following member function:

```
void GClass::InitFunctions()
{ // Initialize arrays of pointers to functions.

ComputeIntLen[0] = &ComputeILS;
ComputeIntLen[1] = &ComputeILE;
ComputeIntLen[2] = &ComputeILI;
PostStep[0] = &PSS;
PostStep[1] = &PSE;
PostStep[2] = &PSI;
gRotation = new Rotation();
}
```

GClass obviously contains all the relevant members -:

```
    void ComputeILE(Int_t, Int_t *, Double_t *);
    void ComputeILI(Int_t, Int_t *, Double_t *);
    void PSS(Int_t , Int_t *, Int_t &, Int_t*);
    void PSE(Int_t, Int_t *, Int_t &, Int_t*);
    void PSI(Int_t , Int_t *, Int_t &, Int_t*);
    ComputeIntLenFunc ComputeIntLen[gNproc];
    PostStepFunc      PostStep[gNproc];
... //other members
}
```

where gNproc is a global const int and ComputeIntLenFunc and PostStepFunc are typedefs like this:

```
typedef void (*ComputeIntLenFunc)(Int_t ntracks, Int_t *trackin, Double_t *lengths);
typedef void (*PostStepFunc)(Int_t ntracks, Int_t *trackin, Int_t &nout, Int_t* trackout);
```

When I Compile this I get gcc gives an error: "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&GClass::ComputeIntLenScattering’ "

When I replace FunctionNames by GClass::FunctionNames in InitFunctions() I get 
    "cannot convert ‘void (GClass::*)(Int_t, Int_t*, Double_t*)’ to ‘void (*)(Int_t, Int_t*, Double_t*)’ in assignment"

Please help me. What topic of C++ is this ?

Comment: OT: GClass is an interesting name for a class. If you read your code, e.g. `GClass something;`, does this mean that `something` _is_ a class? Maybe `GObject` would be slightly better (albeit still very generic).

Answer (score 2):

Non-static member function pointer is different from free function pointer. What you're using is basically free function pointer types, which would not work, as type of `&GClass::ComputeILS` is incompatible with `ComputeIntLenFunc`.

Use this:

```
typedef void (GClass::*ComputeIntLenFunc)(Int_t, Int_t *, Double_t *);
typedef void (GClass::*PostStepFunc)(Int_t, Int_t *, Int_t &, Int_t*);
```

I omitted the parameter names, as they're not required in the typedefs.

Also, you've to use `GClass::` when you get the address of member functions:

```
ComputeIntLen[0] = &GClass::ComputeILS;
ComputeIntLen[1] = &GClass::ComputeILE;
ComputeIntLen[2] = &GClass::ComputeILI;
PostStep[0] = &GClass::PSS;
PostStep[1] = &GClass::PSE;
PostStep[2] = &GClass::PSI;
```

The error message says this very clearly:

> ISO C++ forbids taking the address of **an unqualified** or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function. **Say ‘&GClass::ComputeIntLenScattering**

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend the class to your typedefs as well:

```
typedef void (GClass::*ComputeIntLenFunc)(Int_t ntracks, Int_t *trackin, Double_t *lengths);
typedef void (GClass::*PostStepFunc)(Int_t ntracks, Int_t *trackin, Int_t &nout, Int_t* trackout);
```

Then your (first) type will mean: this is a pointer to a member function in class GClass which takes an `Int_t`, an `Int_t*` and so forth whereas in your version it just referred to a free function with the same parameters.